# Admin on rest change path via custom component click

Tags: reactjs, path, uri, admin-on-rest

I am going to make a custom element which will send you to a path specified in the Admin on rest's menu when you click on this custom element. The path I am going to send the user on should also have filters on it.

Or maybe I want to change which Resource I am using, but with filters on the path.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your usecase ? Where is this custom element going to be used ?

Comment: This custom element are going to be used on a view that are not a List, Edit, or Create view from admin-on-rest it self. I am making my own view where this custom element are visible in. So the custom element are used in a view that has it own custom Route defined in:

<Admin customRoutes={allMyCustomRoutes}>

And I want to go back to one of the not custom routes inside admin on rests Admin, and with this filters I mentioned in my question

Comment: Something like the customers links on the demo: https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest-demo/#/segments ?